# How do I get Application.DoEvents() to allow my Form to move by titlebar mouse drag and not trap during move?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to spawn a very large number of `Task`s on my GUI thread in a loop for fun and it takes longer than a second for all of the `Task`s to be built. As a result, it produces a noticeable freeze in my application. I found that adding `Application.DoEvents()` to my loop enables the controls in the form itself to interact with my mouse—no freeze is observable when I click on check boxes or text fields. However, when I try to move the form by dragging the title bar around, the form stops moving when it reaches my loop which spawns a lot of `Task`s—even though the contents of the form are otherwise interactive.

How do I get something like `Application.DoEvents()` that also executes whatever is necessary for winforms to react to being moved by a titlebar mouse drag?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class MinimalGuiFormMoveFreeze : Form
{    
    async void ButtonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            buttonGo.Enabled = false;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            buttonGo.Text = "Going";

            // 5000 × 1ms = 5s
            await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 5000).Select(async i =>
            {
                // Keep form interactive, but does not allow the user
                // to move the form. How do I allow the user to drag
                // the form?
                Application.DoEvents();

                // Simulate high synchronous method portion of called async method.
                Thread.Sleep(1);

                // Simulate asynchronous portion of called async method.
                await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }));
        }
        finally
        {
            buttonGo.Text = "Go!";
            buttonGo.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    readonly Button buttonGo = new Button
    {
        Text = "&Go",
        Location = new Point(20, 60),
    };

    public MinimalGuiFormMoveFreeze()
    {
        buttonGo.Click += ButtonGo_Click;

        var checkBoxInteractive = new CheckBox
        {
            Text = "I work during Go",
            Location = new Point(20, 20),
        };

        Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{
            checkBoxInteractive,
            buttonGo,
        });
    }
}

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MinimalGuiFormMoveFreeze());
    }
}
```

I have made a [demonstration video](https://youtu.be/QxqUMbsdZmE) showing the window’s failure to continue moving. To experience the issue, you must start moving the window prior to the `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))` expiring.

When working on the minimal repro, I found this interesting fact which points more towards something just being wonky with Windows/.net: the window only stops responding to mouse move requests if I have started moving the window prior to launching lots of `Task`s. If I wait until all the `Task`s start launching, it lets me move the window just fine. However, if you start moving the window after the `Task`s start launching, they do not proceed until you release your drag. It’s as if the window moving operation causes `Application.DoEvents()` to block indefinitely while waiting for a “done moving window” message or something prior to allowing the code to continue.

As a user of various desktop applications, I like to move windows around to monitor them for responsiveness. Though I feel like I have noticed this phenomenon that some windows will never load if they are moved around for particular installers or loading screens. It seems I have accidentally found how to implement this same behavior. Why does this happen and how can I fix it—or should I just use more `Task.Run()`?

Comment: Is the work being done required to be on the main / UI thread?  If not then you can process it in the background which would free it up a lot more.  Also, post some of the code or pseudo code in place for a better answer if you can.

Comment: Also, please don't use the term Window when talking about Windows Forms. Window makes the reader think you are talking about WPF which you clearly aren't. WinForms => Forms, WPF => Windows

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I thought you were going to say the other way of confusion. Each visible window on screen is actually made up of many drawing surfaces which are themselves called windows :-p.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Moving the creation of the `Task`s off the main thread is the easiest way to go, though I thought people recommended to try to avoid unnecessary threading.

Comment: Always avoid unnecessary threading, but if it's not part of the UI / main thread and can be processed on a different thread, especially if it's time consuming and pausing the UI any, it definitely qualifies.

Comment: Show the code. Whenever you need to call such a method, you should notice that you probably are on the wrong track already. There should be simpler ways of coding, especially when `async` and `await` are now available.

Comment: @LexLi Updated with my code.